# Is there a necessary and sufficient condition about a matrix to have distinct eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was thinking about Matrices and its eigenvalues. And I came up with the following question :

Is there a necessary and sufficient condition about a matrix to have distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: What kind of condition are you looking for? A trivial one is that the matrix is similar to a diagonal matrix with distinct diagonal entries.

Comment: yes, when its characteristic polynomial have distinct root, hope this help.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. The usual characterisation is that the characteristic polynomial $p$ splits into linear factors in the underlying field (so that the matrix has a full spectrum) and $p$ has not any double root, i.e. $p$ and $p'$ share no roots. But that may sound cyclic.